# Parse Query time out with FBSUIApplicationSystemService: request to get badge value timed out

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a Parse query written in Swift that queries for all photos by people who are followed by the user. I'm using `query.whereKey("", matchesKey: "", inQuery:)` to get my objects, then after each loop I get the PFFile data, and reload the table view. So the table view should load after each photo is downloaded (photos are only 150x150. The higher the query limit, the less likely any information will load. The page always loads nothing when limit is set to 1000. It usually only works when limit is <= 60.

Sometimes I get `FBSUIApplicationSystemService: request to get badge value timed out` which I have no idea what it means, while other times I get nothing at all. Is this a Parse time-out issue? How can I resolve this?

```
// Reloads table view
    var imageSet:Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if imageSet {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) { // 1
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { // 2
                        self.tableView.reloadData() // 3

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Gets photos
    var dataLoaded:Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if dataLoaded {

                let photoArt = photoCovers.last!
                let indexNumber = find(photoCovers, photoCovers.last!)!

                photoArt.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData, error) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {
                        if let imageData = imageData {
                            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                            self.photoArt[indexNumber] = image
                        }

                    } else {

                        println(error)

                    }
                    self.imageSet = true
                })
            }
            self.imageSet = false
        }
    }

        var innerQuery = PFQuery(className: "Followers")

        innerQuery.whereKey("followerId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Pictures")

        query.whereKey("user", matchesKey: "followingId", inQuery: innerQuery)

        query.limit = 100

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                if let objects = objects {

                    for object in objects {

                        if let user = object["user"]! as? String {

                            if (self.users.filter { $0 == user }.count) < 30 {

                                self.users.append(user)

                                if let caption = object["caption"] as? String {
                                    self.captions.append(caption)
                                }

                                if let photographer = object["photographer"] as? String {
                                    self.photographers.append(photographer)
                                }

                                if let userName = object["userName"] as? String {
                                    self.userNames.append(userName)
                                }

                                if let photoCover = object["photoCover"] as? PFFile {
                                    self.photoCovers.append(photoCover)
                                }

                                if let userId = object["user"] as? String {
                                    self.userIds.append(userId)
                                }

                                self.dataLoaded = true
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            } else {

                println(error)

            }

            self.dataLoaded = false
        }
```